# invoke web service from winfomrs

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I want to invoke a web service from my winforms application in visual studio 2012. So, I have added a service reference to my web service in my project. This service contains two methods. How can I can invoke those methods from my c# code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call it as follows:

```
using Your.Service.Namespace;

// ...

IYourService serviceClientInstance = new YourServiceClient();

serviceClientInstance.SomeServiceMethod();
```

PS: You can see info about the service and available methods by right clicking the reference (under Service References), and selecting *View in object browser*. Among other things, you should see a class `YourServiceNameClient` there, which should have been generated for you, which you can use as above.